# Swipe activated core-drawer-panel?

Tags: polymer

I've thrown together a page based on the paper ui elements and love how mobile-friendly it is. But it does fall short with some functionality. For instance, I'd love for users to be able to swipe out the drawer of my core-drawer-panel, instead of using the button I'v provided on the toolbar.

What I'm looking for is along the lines of the Gmail app for Android.

Does anyone have an example page where this is used to good effect?

Comment: Polymer 1.0 has this.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a pull request pending which will add swipe to open the drawer. [See](https://github.com/Polymer/core-drawer-panel/pull/6) for details.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @AtanuCSE do you think that copying & pasting the code changes and/or the ongoing discussion from the pull request provides any benefit? The answer will become invalid anyway - you might not be aware of the concept of a pull request, but as soon as the pull request is merged core-drawer-panel will provide the currently missing Feature - making both the question and my answer invalid.

Comment: You've given an answer which is not existing yet. This is merely a suggestion which might help to solve the problem in future. You could give this link and draw attention of the user by providing a comment. Lastly what if pull-request won't get merged!

Comment: @AtanuCSE I'm not sure what you mean with "not existing yet"? the modified version of core-drawer-panel exists. Maybe you're not aware of some git concepts: even if the pull-request won't be merged you can clone the repo and use it to get a swipe out for the drawer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [core-scaffold](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-scaffold/demo.html) instead of `core-drawer-panel`

Comment: core-scaffold doesn't do swipe out either. Check the page you linked on a mobile device...